# Tensorflow dynamic_rnn input rank error

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

So, I am trying to use an rnn in tensorflow to generate text. However, once I switched from a static_rnn to a dynamic_rnn, I got this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 654, in with_rank_at_least
    raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank at least %d" % (self, rank))
ValueError: Shape (100, 5) must have rank at least 3
```

This is the part of the code that generates the error:

```
inputs_series = self.input_layer()
with tf.variable_scope(constants.HIDDEN):
    self.hidden_state_placeholder = tf.placeholder(
        dtype=tf.float32, 
        shape=[self.settings.train.batch_size, self.settings.rnn.hidden_size],
        name="hidden_state_placeholder")
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(self.settings.rnn.hidden_size)
    states_series, self.current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        cell=cell, 
        inputs=inputs_series,
        initial_state=self.hidden_state_placeholder)
```

The shape of `inputs_series` is: (10, 5, 100), corresponding to (truncated text length, batch size, number of classes)

The shape of the `hidden_state_placeholder` is (5, 100) for (batch size, hidden state size), but the error persists even when I don't provide an initial state.

The tensorflow version is 1.3, if it helps.

Any insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `time_major == False` in `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`, but your `inputs_series` is `time_major == True`. So maybe change the last statement to

```
states_series, self.current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell=cell, 
    inputs=inputs_series,
    initial_state=self.hidden_state_placeholder,
    time_major=True)
```

Comment: Sorry about the late reply - I only just got to try this, and this did not fix the problem - I got the same error message.

That **was** however a legitimate bug in my code, thanks for catching that!

Comment: `inputs_series = self.input_layer()` I couldn't test this statement, therefore I replace it with a fixed-sized variable (as well as other unknown parameters). Please print the size of `inputs_series` (e.g. `print(inputs_series.get_shape())`). I guess that might have some problem.

Comment: I did the prints, and figured it out. I had a `tf.unstack()` operation going on in `self.input_layer()`, which converted the tensor to a list of 10 tensors. Apparently, that doesn't play well with the dynamic rnn API. Once I removed the unstack operation, everything worked as expected. Thanks for all the suggestions!